# Is there a dot product with which the following linear operator becomes Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the linear operator

$A \in L(M_2(\mathbb{C}))$

$A \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a-b & -a+b \\ d & -c \end{bmatrix}$

Is there a dot product where the operator becomes Hermitian? ($A^*=A$)

I don't know how to prove that there exists one, but I don't know how to construct a dot product either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An hermitian operator is diagonalizable in an orthogonal basis.

- If your operator is not diagonalizable, then it is not hermitian with respect to any inner product.
- If it *is* diagonalizable, pick any basis of eigenvalues and construct an inner product which makes it an orthogonal basis.
- Rejoyce..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space is self-adjoint w.r.t. some inner product, its eigenvalues must be real (see the [proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_of_Self-Adjoint_Operator_are_Real) on ProofWiki). Now the matrix representation of the linear operator $A$ w.r.t. the standard basis of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
-1&0&1&0\\
0&-1&0&0}.
$$
What are the eigenvalues of $A$?